# Different speed results between Chrome(Edge) and Mozilla on this stopwatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dear all professionals from everywhere.
I have a question from a beginner. I did not find any direct answers only some references...
I wrote a simple version of stopwatch (React) and when I try to test it on different browsers (Chrome, Mozilla and Edge) I have different speed results between Chrome(Edge) and  Mozilla on this stopwatch. The difference is about 4 times.
I would be very grateful if you also send me a link with some theory (maybe).

Anyway thank you

P.S If you see something that seems strange in this code please tell me. That would be very useful for me.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import "./Stopwatch.css";
    import Button from "./Button";
    import Round from "./Round";
    
    function Stopwach() {
      const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
      const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
      const [round, setRound] = useState([]);
      const [globeTimer, setGlobeTimer] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let secondsCircle = document.querySelector(".svg01");
        let milCircle = document.querySelector(".svg02");
        let degreeS = 0;
        let degreeM = 0;
    
        degreeS = timer / 166.6666666666667;
        secondsCircle.style.transform = `rotate(${degreeS}deg)`;
        degreeM = timer / 3.6;
        milCircle.style.transform = `rotate(${degreeM}deg)`;
      }, [timer]);
    
      function Circle() {
        if (round.length < 10) {
          if (round.length === 0) {
            round[round.length] = timer;
            setRound(round);
          } else {
            round[round.length] = timer - globeTimer;
            setRound(round);
          }
        } else {
          let firstElement = Math.min.apply(Math, round);
          round.length = 0;
          round[0] = firstElement;
          round[round.length] = timer - globeTimer;
          setRound(round);
        }
        setGlobeTimer(timer);
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let interval;
        if (start) {
          interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimer((timer) => timer + 4);
          }, 1);
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        return () => {
          clearInterval(interval);
        };
      }, [start]);
    
      function go() {
        setStart(!start);
      }
    
      function clear() {
        setTimer(0);
        setRound([]);
        setGlobeTimer([])
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="main_monitor">
          <div className="svg">
            <div className="svg01"></div>
            <div className="svg02"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="main_monitor__timer">
            <div className="mill">
              {Math.trunc(timer / 1000 / 60) < 10 ? `0${Math.trunc(timer / 1000 / 60)}` : Math.trunc(timer / 1000 / 60)}
            </div>
            <div className="point">:</div>
            <div className="mill">
              {Math.trunc(timer / 1000) % 60 < 10 ? `0${Math.trunc(timer / 1000) % 60}` : Math.trunc(timer / 1000) % 60}
            </div>
            <div className="point">.</div>
            <div className="mill">{timer % 1000 < 10 ? `00${timer % 1000}` : timer % 1000 < 100 ? `0${timer % 1000}` : timer % 1000} </div>
          </div>
          <div className="main_monitor__btns">
            <Button go={go} btn={"play"} />
            <Button go={go} btn={"stop"} />
            <Button go={clear} btn={"recycle"} />
            <Button go={Circle} btn={"history"} />
          </div>
          <Round rounds={round} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Stopwach;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after 5 days and hole bunch of coffee...
According to Wiki - Firefox, Google and Edge is browsers with different engines.
I think, at least, it`s the root of this mistake.

I solved this with Date() constructor. Every time when we call setInterval - we will ask new "a single moment in time in a platform-independent format" (unfortunatly this part of definition was not translated (en - ru) on MDN). And based on this "single moment" we can calculate how much time passed from our time point...